# what is the proper way to dynamically build an object that you KNOW should meet all of its requirements?

Tags: typescript

I have a text file, with environment variables:

```
RDS_USERNAME=me
RDS_PASSWORD=lol
```

My goal is to read the file and assign the values to an object, and later use that object for building credentials.

```
interface Secrets {
  RDS_DB_PASSWORD?: string,
  RDS_DB_USERNAME?: string,
};
const secrets: Secrets = {};

fs.readFileSync('./lib/secrets', 'utf8')
  .split("\n")
  .filter((entry: string) => entry.length)
  .map((entry: string) => {
    const tuple = entry.split('=');
    const key   = tuple[0] as keyof Secrets;
    const value = tuple[1];
    secrets[key] = value;
  });

if (!secrets.RDS_DB_USERNAME || !secrets.RDS_DB_PASSWORD) {
  throw('missing rds credentials!');
}
```

I was already annoyed that I have to do `as keyof Secrets` because that feels like I am "faking" typechecking...

But anyway, despite writing a guard check that throws an error if either of these values are missing, typescript is apparently too dumb to see that, and gets mad when trying to use the credentials saying that:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    'username': cdk.SecretValue.unsafePlainText(secrets.RDS_DB_USERNAME),
```

So, the only ways around this (that I can see) is to write even more dumb code, which I hate to do......  or use `any` which I also hate to do..  So I am hoping someone here can show me an alternate way to write this that can be less dumb and actually properly make use of type checking.

I had to add the `?` to the interface keys, because I am building the object up one by one............  I just don't understand how one is supposed to do something like this without writing absolutely horrific code that makes you hate yourself and your life.

Comment: `as keyof Secrets a isn't ‘faking’ type checking, it’s overriding it.  `key` could be a value that’s not a key of Secrets.  You need an assertion so that it can be sure of the type.  Your type guard isn’t narrowing to string (e.g excluding the possibility of undefined) hence the error.  Unless you need to avoid a dependency, Zod is a good tool for validating input against a schema.  As an aside, I think you’re missing the point of AWS Secrets Manager if you’re going to put credentials in text files.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I typically use, defining your `Secrets` interface with required properties but constructing a `Partial<Secrets>` object to use when constructing it. You then create a function that returns a `Secrets` object, so the partial object only exists within that function.

In this example I've also included custom type checks, which unfortunately also involves writing the functions to do those checks (or finding a tool to generate them). If you wanted to, you could replace these checks with type assertions and they will serve the same purpose of stopping TypeScript from complaining, with the downside of course being that you may lose type safety (particularly if the code changes in the future).

I usually use a tool I made myself for generating type definitions, called [TypeGuardian](https://cipscis.github.io/typeguardian/) but it's a hobby project and I know there are more robust, fleshed out, and widely used tools for the same purpose out there. I just unfortunately don't know enough about any of them to recommend one to you.

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';

interface Secrets {
  RDS_DB_PASSWORD: string,
  RDS_DB_USERNAME: string,
};
function isSecret(obj: unknown): obj is Secrets {
  if (!(
    typeof obj === 'object' &&
    obj !== null
  )) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!(
    'RDS_DB_PASSWORD' in obj &&
    typeof obj['RDS_DB_PASSWORD'] === 'string'
  )) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!(
    'RDS_DB_USERNAME' in obj &&
    typeof obj['RDS_DB_USERNAME'] === 'string'
  )) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

function isKeyofSecret(key: unknown): key is keyof Secrets {
  return key === 'RDS_DB_PASSWORD' || key === 'RDS_DB_USERNAME';
}

function getSecrets(): Secrets {
  const secret: Partial<Secrets> = {};

  fs.readFileSync('./lib/secrets', 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter((entry) => entry.length)
    .map((entry) => {
      const [key, value] = entry.split('=');
      if (isKeyofSecret(key)) {
        secrets[key] = value;
      }
    })

  if (!isSecret(secret)) {
    // Handle error somehow
    throw new TypeError('Could not completely construct secrets');
  }

  return secret;
}

const secrets = getSecrets();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wGbo1CI4DkWBA3AFBnAB2MAplBsgMa1wDKtTUtM6A3mThwASgBE2AfVEAhCQAUAgmzYB1APJiAXHFQwo1AOYAaQSPFTZAVTYBRYQDkFAWRvbd+qsbIBfchgCuVEwwwBBUcMCoHFw8ABQQAEYAVtqBANZUEADuVACU2olJEejR3LxwAkLAGHCxAISxpkIwAJ5gtBA1hXAAvH2EhZwwBHAAZKNNcN11-VT+ADbzprm5FZNl-lDhjPOotORC3hRVNfWNQkIEYpIy8kqqGqIj1FPJYxMXcK3tna9JANpXcy3RTKdRiAgAXV6-QI7kMBGWq0qFw2W0wyF2+1MR1M1VqDUmQJuVlsDmcNme4W640m3w6XWSgOuFgk1jsjhcUJhPUI8M8iKEKzWnzR20xewOcFxQjFXyg-mxvgoASCITCxQA0rQWp1SnE0jrUlQMtk8tpDS1inBLb99eUUXLLTzCCyQfdwU84AAfb02nUu4ms9nkrnkXGq4KhcIGHj21CxfLsThlfimJhhXQ6FM8bRyZCwYCYgA88YAfL0KsrTFgAHTcZAAEwAYsB5rQ2C0grECLWAPTzYAJPt7GK8AhGQj+GAYAAcBFyk1rqDAg5gPYAOlQF0uMG26FBYrFaDQoC1Vj0Kye9C1a+3PDAABaLz61kDIMBH69ni8VlGfDMqCzf5LUnAA3TFFWhXlv1vFc1x7HoFylT58ViSJtV1DB7ViS1hX-T5szHVAQJ1aC4Ag+ZFRQi4jk+bxFzxU46kiHDRzKfDJj7Ps4AACWQKhG3bOB6FwKAdDwWhH2yOlH1wLI4CoWgFIAFTaWgbCgMSewAYQgBZG0UiB4AzcB2zoeYrUA9x-GCIjU2QnFjjgOV2J4cMKGs+A3PKXlYxgeNE3IIA)

Comment: although I greatly appreciate your answer and thoughts, this is exactly the kind of code I absolutely hate being forced to write.........  I ended up doing something different which still required me to do some ridiculousness such as `if (key === userkey) { user = value; } else if (key === passKey) { password = value; }` but that seemed like the best compromise to me.

Comment: Yeah, writing these functions is a pain. That's why I made myself a tool to automate it. But if you want the safety of type checking there's not really a way around it, you'd need to tell TypeScript how to do that type check. I most often use this approach when I need to parse a JSON response from an API.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the properties required and use `Object.fromEntries` to create the object.

```
interface Secrets {
   RDS_DB_PASSWORD: string;
   RDS_DB_USERNAME: string;
};
const secrets: Secrets = Object.fromEntries(fs.readFileSync('./lib/secrets', 'utf8')
  .split("\n").filter(Boolean).map(entry => entry.split('=')));
```

Comment: Unfortunately the only reason TypeScript doesn't complain about this is because it's using `any` under the hood, within `Object.fromEntries` which is typed as `ObjectConstructor.fromEntries(entries: Iterable<readonly any[]>): any`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
const rdsSecrets: { RDS_DB_USERNAME: string, RDS_DB_PASSWORD: string } = (() => {
  let username!: string;
  let password!: string;

  fs.readFileSync(RDS_SECRETS_PATH, 'utf8')
    .split("\n")
    .filter((entry: string) => entry.length)
    .map((entry: string) => {
      const tuple = entry.split('=');
      const key = tuple[0];
      const value = tuple[1];
      if (key === 'RDS_DB_USERNAME') {
        username = value;
      } else if (key === 'RDS_DB_PASSWORD') {
        password = value;
      }
    });

  if (!username || !password) { throw('rds credentials missing!'); }
  return {
    RDS_DB_USERNAME: username,
    RDS_DB_PASSWORD: password,
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you end up using, you'll need to determine what constitutes a valid input file format. This is important, because it will strongly inform the algorithm of your parser.

For example: if a value for a line (on the right side of the `=`) can include the `=` character, then you'll need to split each line on the first index of the `=`, rather than on every instance with the assumption of only one instance per line. The fewer assumptions that you make in your code, the safer your program will be.

For this reason, it's generally a better idea to use existing tools that have been worked on and tested by many developers, proven to be reliable in widespread use over a long period of time. However, sometimes such tools just don't exist for certain cases — you have to make that determination. Here's an example of such an env file parser library: [`https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/tree/0.193.0/dotenv`](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/tree/0.193.0/dotenv).

You can use a TypeScript compiler feature ([`const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters) to automatically build the type that you want by inferring the keys from an input tuple of string literal keys:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhA1nAhgZw5zBTWOAXzgDMoIQ4AiAOwgBM8AuLfWAekximAGMY1ANwAoUJEJIoedAwBiwADZ4AygE9afYmQpU6jFqUzCRI0gFdNMYBFpww6KPgCitAG4AePre5wA0nB4AB4weLQM2Ny8tADmAHwAFCJwcKEhAMK2obQwzHBRwLEANMlwKHhqmHnSsraKav4A2gC6JQCUeQBKeN5QDB5+Rfk8hfGIpd60vmEjeNgAvHAA8gBGAFY9MAB05JSus5hJKSlpMJk5M6XHcFsjIAltV8dbmGCKwDAJ1AA6tNSP1xSWxA6DAHkaBWKw2iMWaiQS71oeDacHmcXGgOOiLwqLg2NuvHubVEmJSk18wFx+MKTCCS1IX3m-1ET2uHA4-gqGHCcDc6EU5hxyliMAAFhhpIF0HxxTEaqEoKlReg7AAGVnHNgET4a66U9GquAAMiNcEpHjxhTwW2FMTFcAAtHAAIwlUnHAAGAFUkUEwJs8AwyNAQfBSBBLEHw4rCmBzPBsXlqAASBDYojUD1u0nE0zu6QwcxQOyNfGYd58PAJVVDYBtIZlitVykAahdbWaJMBRHrpVzEx88DCblxCBIWDg3V6-UG0NGcRZKWjcAS5Pg5QaEFIZQqmBRCCeWtgCQ3ZrsM14cyGHr8XPoYYjPMKZ7juRoqY3GY9ueuw8aG+aXEL2AOZ-wqZoAEIuyIPM4ALItz3cUQYJENdAncXEHCcPBXDcI5jnZAA9AB+UoankJRVA0Pgvi2Dh3hWLgegLYwhiQMJvAYUYk3jUgAA5qGIXsUkaahOgAERUAB9L0VGcToADkAEEAFlnGoIYxMkqSAAUlJUFQAHUlgk6hWhEfsYDUf04Fw28GkWDct1Say8Gc4cuyI0iRGHLYJOkvSDOMiTSi8nz3D87TZPk5S1NCjgSJEIA)

```ts
import { ok as assert } from "node:assert/strict";
import { readFileSync } from "node:fs";

function parseEnv<const K extends string>(
  textContent: string,
  keys: readonly K[],
): Record<K, string> {
  const entries = Object.fromEntries(
    textContent
      .trim()
      .split("\n")
      .map<[string, string]>((line) => {
        line = line.trim();
        const i = line.indexOf("=");

        // Key and value length are each greater than 0
        assert(
          i > 0 && i < line.length - 1,
          `Unexpected format found for input line: "${line}"`,
        );

        return [line.slice(0, i), line.slice(i + 1)];
      }),
  );

  const env = {} as Record<K, string>;

  for (const key of keys) {
    assert(key in entries, `Key not found in input: "${key}"`);
    env[key] = entries[key]!;
  }

  return env;
}

const env = parseEnv(
    //^? const env: Record<"RDS_USERNAME" | "RDS_PASSWORD", string>
  readFileSync("./lib/secrets", { encoding: "utf8" }),
  ["RDS_USERNAME", "RDS_PASSWORD"],
);

type EnvKey = keyof typeof env;
  //^? type EnvKey = "RDS_USERNAME" | "RDS_PASSWORD"

env.RDS_PASSWORD
  //^? RDS_PASSWORD: string
env.RDS_USERNAME
  //^? RDS_USERNAME: string
```

Compiled JS demo from the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/PTAEBUAsFMGdtAOQPYBMEEsC2AHZAnAF1lFWQDsByQ0AdwIGtQNzRCZQAjfZW+fUAEMa7DCULZoALgBQIZrgI0A3qGRNBJTfxoBfUADMeWUACJyaaduhFgsQvgwBjQqYDccsNjxFQq-NCCqABiGAA20ADKAJ7kTqD6Rsgm5pZSBrDuMjJOYdqgAIKwOhgUAKL4PALQAB6E0OSoJBVVfjKgagBuNo7ooOSCWAgAvGZFJeWVBFm62QYArnESFELFNoQAFLU4+FKgiwwWtOQANKBYsADmAPx79o7klwCUe9ZEJNsCyu3MBqAbAEJPk82JAeLR+tAIeN1qVyC0CBsLs8PLMZAslnDQDhBPh4GVyJ0ADxOCj2UAAaVAtXqjRI9xYlwAfBsfvU6gBhCi0wh3ByMk4-BjQaKwPYBIIUMLRSkAbQAuoKXqAAErQUn4VBEilnBmPJltDqk8jkhr8uCgUYAeU4ACt1YQAHRJLAE82wVkdDrswhc8g8n5e0CO-lYDZPQNex2wHBhDCbUwAHXIpgjQY6jqwghwRNlesuuv5j3lLI2cfI0BBwwN33TXvLI1ADZDjjDTw8daNZJoGEtTZY0EdLHQNStBg2pmGqY8kaD8gpIqEjVAnUEYXmCAij3YQgC1METkgoEuEvqAnYglYAAZZ163ptb0Hewar6AAGRv5igIn9iuOreXDuAC0oAAIyCp2XoAAYAKoVjUOAOtAqCGAQWY0AYyCLChmECCwODzDQDZ7KYAAkygNrophQRBnbttkkEBIQ8z4KwsrNrAcZONAGxXmcGBPGcHFcTxvYANRgU88odumuiCT89E-MapqEn2yj6JoqrqgQWo6qA+ZMjOHS4f8yk0MKMrIH8FmwCCtZ3msRAbBZzCsGajhwGcUELjKFgYVhy4sK5BG8mY5EWVRUH0UGDSdLKFnyn27kYHA8UivKAIyWiHRMSxbmEqi2TyAAssgThMCZogkNwvD8NSNSDLG0joosLhYhKIThFEsROBsjr9Ti+CDGK+zkIcvDkAqyr5oaoC5axoBQSqAAikQAPowZEZQqogBTFWUwxDMmK3rQACgUkSRAA6laK3DGEyBhMmUGFTk3bUqpoyDfihKel6IAAHrXD8HWhBEMRxBOjrAHGnB2OqTGZGcqgNKSqCMiRhEGAAHKYCTyR0sqmCdG1bTte1lKYZzE6ta3nZdN0raYioyIphDRIhoAEp0Pl9hZVlsBz0AC7FMmA8DMixY6JP09dt3LT84uS4S0u05t227ftivAED2TKY9g4PZcWyEvRQA):

```js
"use strict";
class AssertionError extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.name = "AssertionError";
    }
}
function assert(expr, msg) {
    if (!expr)
        throw new AssertionError(msg);
}
function parseEnv(textContent, keys) {
    const entries = Object.fromEntries(textContent
        .trim()
        .split("\n")
        .map((line) => {
        line = line.trim();
        const i = line.indexOf("=");
        assert(i > 0 && i < line.length - 1, `Unexpected format found for input line: "${line}"`);
        return [line.slice(0, i), line.slice(i + 1)];
    }));
    const env = {};
    for (const key of keys) {
        assert(key in entries, `Key not found in input: "${key}"`);
        env[key] = entries[key];
    }
    return env;
}
function readFileSync(...params) {
    return `RDS_USERNAME=me\nRDS_PASSWORD=lol\n`;
}
const env = parseEnv(readFileSync("./lib/secrets", { encoding: "utf8" }), ["RDS_USERNAME", "RDS_PASSWORD"]);
env.RDS_PASSWORD;
env.RDS_USERNAME;
console.log(env);
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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
```